# Replace SEO title tag with dynamically generated value

Tags: seo, amazon

I have a page that pulls data from amazon product api and returns the data for a category, based on the category ID.

The script runs in a hook whitch outputs the data in a page from a custom post type (labeled amazon) I created for the purpose

Everything works as expected except that I want the Name of that category to replace the **SEO (or HTML) TITLE tag of** that post type.

Here is where I am stuck

In the script that calls the amazon. api, at some point, I retrieve the value of the category title:

```
$newtitle = $Category_Title_From_Json_Response;
```

Then I store the value in a global variable so it can be accessed from other scripts. (suggestions from chatGPT)

```
global $custom_document_title;
$custom_document_title = $newtitle;
```

Then In my functions.php file, still suggested by chatGPT, I have this code:

```
    add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', function( $title ) {
    // Access the global variable containing the dynamic title.
    global $custom_document_title;
    
    if ( is_singular( 'amazon' ) && isset( 
       $custom_document_title ) ) {
       
      // $newtitle = "My custom title"; // This works 
        $newtitle = $custom_document_title; // This does not pick the value and returns NULL :-(
    
    
    
    } else {
        // Otherwise, use the default title.
        $newtitle = $title;
    }
    
    return $newtitle;
    
    }, 999, 1 );
```

btw, I am using Yoast SEO plugin, just in case it would interfere?

So, how can I pass the value of $newtitle from the hook to the filter?

I hope this makes sense

Thank You already

PS: it's quite straightforward replacing the document.title in Javascript but I'm not sure google will pick it up.

Comment: "This does not pick the value and returns NULL :-(" - you're possibly not doing your store bit at the right time then. Is it in an init hook? Why not just compute the title at the point you need it, in that filter? I assume you're caching the Amazon product API calls in a transient or similar.

Comment: I'd hope Yoast SEO would use wp_get_document_title() as its og:title etc. by default but that might be a question for them if it's not.

Comment: Rup 5  I would compute the title at the point at need it, in fact, that's what I believe I'm doing. I'm not a pro developper by any means, I managed to make the call to the api and return the result in my wordpress reading and googling, I'm just stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`use` clause](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-181):

```php
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', function ( $title ) use ( $custom_document_title ) {
    ...
} );
```

You can remove the `global $custom_document_title;` line with `use`.

Comment: Thanks, tried it but still no good.
$custom_document_title value is not being passed from the script where it is set to the function where it is being called

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$custom_document_title` just before adding the callback? It may be helpful to move the logic that populates the variable to inside of the callback, or inside of a global function (rather than variable).

Comment: Caleb, the value of $custom_document_title is NULL (however the value is a string in the script calling the function.

How do I move the logic to inside of a global function?

Comment: I don't know what the logic is, so I can't help with that. But you define a global function like `function get_doc_title() {}`.